# Making a decentralized system utilizing JavaScript/HTML5?

Tags: javascript, html5, websockets

I am interested in decentralized systems, and am currently considering building one myself. I am considering using JavaScript and HTML5, simply because it makes it very easy to use the system (they just have to go to a website).

Some thoughts:

- I may or may not use another decentralized network for storage, and even if I do, I probably want to cache stuff on the client. If I do not, I **need** to store stuff on the client, since the information will then be distributed on **my** network. Is any of the HTML5 storage models good for this? I've read somewhere that they have a size limit.
- When using JavaScript in the browser, my understanding is that I have to use WebSockets instead of regular sockets. Doesn't this force me to use WebSocket in my "protocol spec"?

Comment: You might want to clarify exactly what it is you're trying to build.

Comment: What I'm trying to build is essentially a network which will store a list of short strings (maybe a hundred characters each). Anyone can add a string to the network, presumably by broadcasting it to other nodes.

Answer (score 1):

> If I do not, I need to store stuff on the client, since the
>   information will then be distributed on my network. Is any of the
>   HTML5 storage models good for this? I've read somewhere that they have
>   a size limit.

The only way I know how to distribute data in your scenario is with a web server  component. If you want to store your data client side only ( via HTML5 local storage, webSQL, or indexedDB)  you could implement a http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gossip_protocol on the web server, to reflect all data communicated from clients to each other.

> When using JavaScript in the browser, my understanding is that I have
>   to use WebSockets instead of regular sockets. Doesn't this force me to
>   use WebSocket in my "protocol spec"?

You don't *have* to use Websockets. You could accomplish this with ajax and polling. Websockets however does enable you to easily *push* data from the server
to the client, so it would make the implementation of your gossip protocol easier. One client posts a message that they have saved locally, and your Websockets enabled web server relays the message to all other clients, who then store the data locally.

Recommendations:
- if you want to use JavaScript across the board, try Node.js and the SocketIO library
- if you want to not have to write the server component, you could try something like https://www.firebase.com/

As for local storage, from html5 rocks: "“5 megabytes” is how much storage space each origin gets by default. This is surprisingly consistent across browsers, although it is phrased as no more than a suggestion in the HTML5 Storage specification."